# Define and Retrieve key-values in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to define a document in MongoDB  in order to keep a list of key-value pairs in addition to some more information . I need to query on keys and extract just values , not whole the document.  Let’s say it looks like:

```
{  title :” Do not stop me now”
   Artist: “Queen”
   Info :{
    Metadata: [
    {key: “genre”, value: “Rock” },
    {key: “bps”, value: 120}
    ]
   }
}
```

I selected this format based on http://java.dzone.com/articles/indexing-schemaless-documents

I want to query like select “genre” from song where artist is “Queen” 
My current code is:

```
BasicDBObject eleMatch = new BasicDBObject();
eleMatch.put("key","genre");
BasicDBObject up = new BasicDBObject();
up.put("$elemMatch",eleMatch);


BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("info.Metadata", up);
query.put(“Artist”,”Queen”);
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("info.Metadata.$",1).append("_id", false); 
DBObject object =collection.findOne(query,fields);
```

I tried to extract value like:

```
System.out.println( (((BasicBSONList) ((BasicBSONObject)    object.get("info")).get("Metadata")).get("value")).toString());
```

But I cannot get access to "value"

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The positional operator return an array of one element. So, what you are converting to string is an array and of course you will get a kind of java id.
Cast it to array and get its first element

Comment: To be more precise I get an error:   BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [value]. Do you still think it is the problem with ToString? If this is the case, how I should do that?

Comment: As I analyse, I see that what I said is not completely acurate. However, I do not understand why you are getting that error. To make it easy, go with simple steps: BasicBSONObject step1 = (BasicBSONObject) object.get("info"); BasicBSONList step2 = (BasicBSONList) step1.get("Metadata"); String step3 = (String) step2.get("value"); and call System.out.println on step3. That way you can catch the point that created the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that. The problem is about the last part, value. When I add the last part, I get that error:(

Comment: Did you try on mongo shell to see the result?

Comment: Not yet, I will do it and let you know about the result!